# Installing Skyrim on a new computer/OS

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam, technical-issues, ubuntu

I'm trying to transfer all my files over from my laptop, which is slow and laggy, to my newer desktop, which is nice and fast. I want to be able to play Skyrim on it. I've been looking into how to transfer the game over to it, but all the answers I find are how to move the save files and access them after, etc. That's good, but my current question is how to get the *game* on my new computer?
I saw one reply to someone that you have to install it. Ok, that makes sense. But do I have to pay for a whole new version of Skyrim? Or how would I just install the one I already bought a couple years ago? I don't have it on Steam, though I'm not sure why since I thought I remembered buying it on there. A little confused about that cause I have Skyrim Script Extender on there. Is this what I'm looking for?

The desktop is running Ubuntu, I've installed WINE already, and I'm not sure if I need to get anything else. My laptop is running Windows 10 and it's messed up so I can't use it, but I refuse to lose my Skyrim saves!

Not moving it to a different folder within the computer, but moving it from an entirely different computer using an entirely different OS.

Comment: How did you install it the first time?

Comment: @arghtype The process of moving games to another disk is a lot different from moving them to another system entirely.

Comment: Rillewin, the best solution will stand or fall with you having Skyrim on Steam or not. If you log in to Steam, does it list the game in your 'Library'?

Comment: @Joachim, yes, but 2nd most upvoted answer there could be used here as is. And any other answer could be used after mounting old machine as external drive if LAN connection is possible.

Comment: thanks for the answers guys. So I looked at the links you provided and none of that looks helpful to me. Joachim: No, Skyrim is not listed on my Steam list. Just Skyrim script extender. This puzzles me because I remember having to get Skyrim through steam because of some issue with the disk I bought not having the code that goes with it. – Rillewen

Comment: It doesn't make sense for Skyrim Script Extender to be in your Steam games list, unless you manually put it there as external software. And can you elaborate on "some issue with the disk I bought not having the code that goes with it"?

Comment: I added the script extender myself, yes, so I could get mods and stuff.
As for the disk, it's been a few years so I'm trying to remember the details. As I recall, I bought the game used, online, cause I was really eager to get to play it. Then, when it came, they didn't have the code included, so I messaged them about it and they refunded my money but then I had no way to play the disk I had. Then, as I recall, I went online searching for a way to play it, and I don't really remember exactly what solution I came up with but I'm pretty sure I ended up just buying it on steam.

Comment: "How to get the game on my new computer?" Have you tried logging in to the Steam Client in Ubuntu and downloading Skyrim? Skyrim can only be played through Steam on PC (regardless of where you bought it). So if you've already played it previously on your laptop, all you have to do is log in to the same Steam account you've used. You do not have to pay for it again if playing on the same Steam account. Reports say that [Skyrim works great with Proton](https://www.protondb.com/app/72850) (Valve's Wine fork for Steam).

Comment: Galacticninja: I have already logged into Steam, and as I stated before, skyrim is not listed in my games there. 
I've been trying to remember, and I think that I downloaded the game from an online source, I just don't remember what source that was. I don't know if I need to buy the game (again) on Steam or not.

Comment: @Rillewen If Skyrim is not listed, then it is possible you haven't bought it in that account. You might need to find out which account you used to purchase Skyrim. Check email addresses that you might have used to make a Steam account. Also, see: [How do I get my game back on Steam?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/341137/4797)